# How to debug Django while using pipenv and VS Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, virtualenv, pipenv

I'm been using VS code and `venv` for my Django projects and have been able to debug using the tutorial provided by Microsoft here.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django

However, I have now switched to `pipenv` instead which I activate using the commmand `pipenv shell`.

When I now run using the Django debug configuration I get an error.

```
Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? 
Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I can't find any resources to guide me on this.

Do I need to change the launch.json file to make it work with pipenv?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 1):

you just need to choose an interpreter
in my case, all pipenv interpreters are located in the ~/.virtualenvs folder
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGYeN.png)